# While loop with array push for get_field ACF plugin not working

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, filter, while-loop

Please could someone tell me what I am doing wrong with my code?

The Loop is not working.

When I do this the whole page is blank.

```
 function filter_reports() {
   global $customer_account;
   $args = array(
     'post_type' => 'ebooks',
     'tax_query' => array(
       'relation' => 'AND',
       array(
         'taxonomy' => 'customer',
         'field'    => 'term_id',
         'terms'    => $customer_account,
       ),
       array(
         'taxonomy' => 'disease',
         'field'    => 'term_id',
         'terms'    => $_POST['options'],
       )
     ),
   );

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
$results = array();

   if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
     while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    $id =  get_the_ID();
      array_push($results, array(
        'id' => $id,
        'title' => get_field('title', $id),
        'chair' => get_field('e-chair', $id),
      ));
    }
  }

  echo json_encode($results);
  die;

}
  add_action( 'wp_ajax_filter_reports', 'filter_reports' );
  add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_filter_reports', 'filter_reports' );
```

I want to get the custom fields that I made in the ACF Plugin to be looped in my while loop.
But the whole WHILE is not working.

I really hope someone can help me with this.

Comment: I would guess ( not bing a WP expert ) that you have written an infinite while loop there

Comment: what should i do? i'm getting stuck.

Comment: Use a call in the while loop that actually attempts to consume the result set, rather than one that just asks if there is anything in the resultset

Comment: are you sure the `$the_query` returns filtered posts?

Comment: Yes because when i echo thje result i get an array with the id of the category that i want to filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You while loop is not working because you didn't iterate the post
>   index in the loop, which has to be set inside the while loop by
>   [`the_post()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_post/).

So your code should look something like this:

```
$the_query = new WP_Query($args);
$results = array();
while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post();
    $id = get_the_ID();
    array_push($results, array(
        'id' => $id,
        'title' => get_field('title', $id),
        'chair' => get_field('e-chair', $id),
    ));
endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Alternate method:

```
$the_query = new WP_Query($args);
$results = array();
if (!empty($the_query->posts))
{
    foreach ($the_query->posts as $post)
    {
        $id = $post->ID;
        array_push($results, array(
            'id' => $id,
            'title' => get_field('title', $id),
            'chair' => get_field('e-chair', $id),
        ));
    }
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It did help but still not looping great so i will be making another question for this